# What does 'article' mean in grammar?

Tags: articles

> Turkish, unlike many Indo-European languages, contains no articles at all!

This sentence is in the welcome page of the Turkish course on Duolingo, I tried to search for it, but I couldn't find any explanation. What does 'article' mean in that context?

Comment: Google for "article grammar" gives hundreds of relevant results. If you read some of those and you have some more specific questions to ask, those would be ideal for this site!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Articles in English are either definite (`the`) or indefinite (`a/an`).

You use **definite** article when talking about something specific, e.g."the cat which belongs to our neighbor".

Use **indefinite** one when the other person we are talking to doesn't know what exactly we are referring to, e.g. "There was a white dog."

You also have to consider that you use articles only when referring to countable nouns.

**Edit** (thanks to Sander's comment): There is also the **zero article** which defines those cases where there is no article preceding a noun. This occurs in case of mass nouns and plural nouns with indefinite reference, e.g. "Cats are fast."

See more info about [articles in general](http://esl.fis.edu/grammar/rules/article.htm), [definite article](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/determiners-and-quantifiers/definite-article), [indefinite articles](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/determiners-and-quantifiers/indefinite-article-and) and [zero article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-marking_in_English#Zero_article) and their usage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I still have a time ban on the question, when its gone I will mark this as an answer.

Comment: You forgot about the *zero article*. This article is the indefinite article for plural nouns. It's not actually written, but still considered an article. *a pizza* has *a* as an article, while *pizzas* has the zero article.